# powershell recurse delete files in subfolders

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script to search for duplicate base file names with different extensions in subfolders under a path.

For example a folder may contain file1.zip and file1.pdf and I want to delete the PDFs only on the duplicates inside the folder.

I came with this which will will work only for the set path in the path variable. Adding `-recurse` to the `Get-Child Item` doesn't seem to work.

```
$Path = "C:\logs"

ForEach ($File in (Get-ChildItem $Path\*.pdf))
{   If ((Test-Path "$Path\$($File.Basename).zip"))
    {   $File | Remove-Item 
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get this logic to apply to all subfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is what you need. The problem you were having is that you weren't providing the correct path. Since you are using `-Recurse`, the path `$Path\$($File.Basename).zip` is not always correct, for it is correct **only** if the file is an immediate child of `$Path`.

```
$path = "C:\logs"
Get-ChildItem $path\*.pdf -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    if( Test-Path "$($_.DirectoryName)\$($_.Basename).zip" ) {
        Remove-Item "$($_.DirectoryName)\$($_.Basename).pdf"
    }
}
```